# What should be the duration of a simple tap event (not long press) in a mobile app?

Tags: mobile-application, touch-screen, tap

We are building a mobile app that does not use any long press interactions in its UI. However, we observed some users tapping longer than expected when trying to open the menu. As they tapped too long for the event to be triggered the menu didn’t open. Is there a usability standard for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some OS based standards for this. For example, iOS has 3D touch for hard touches and you can rearrange your home screen after a long tap. When you hold your tap in navigation the touch event will be triggered on release.

**However, there might be something bigger happening here. Why are your users having a long tap?**

The best thing to do here is figure out why users hold the tap longer than you were expecting. Maybe your users are insecure about what to expect after the tap. It's better to fix the deep issue here than to put a patch on it by fitting it into a usability standard.

Comment: Hi Nick, 

thanks for your quick reply!
As it happens with a rather ordinary interaction (opening the burger menu) my assumption is that it occurs when users feel a general unease because some things in the UI are not working as expected (yet), due to the (unfinished) state of the app. So it's hard to attribute it to one single reason. Maybe it makes sense to check again how people's behaviour changes over time when the UI becomes more refined?

Comment: That makes sense. However, one of the downsides of using a hamburger menu is that users do not know what's part of the menu. That might cause the unease also.